# How to programmatically create a collection on GSA with Python

Tags: python, xml, google-search-appliance

I am attempting to create a collection on a Google Search Appliance using the [Administrative API](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/70/gsa_doc_set/acapi_protocol/acapi_protocol.html#1073562)

I successfully retrieve an authorization token but when posting XML to create the collection I get errors about my xml.

```
<errors xmlns=\'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005\'><error><domain>GData</domain><code>ParseException</code><internalReason>Element type "gsa:content" must be followed by either attribute specifications, "&gt;" or "/&gt;".</internalReason></error></errors>
```

Here is my payload:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:gsa='http://schemas.google.com/gsa/2007'>
<gsa:content name='collectionName'>testcollection</gsa:content>
<gsa:content name='insertMethod''>default</gsa:content>
</entry>
```

And here is my python:

```
>> print headers
{'Content-Type': 'application/atom+xml', 'Authorization': 'GoogleLogin auth=googleauthtoken'}
>>> print url
http://GSA_ip:8000/feeds/collection
>>> r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, verify=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a blind fool:

```
<gsa:content name='insertMethod''>default</gsa:content>
```

Two single quotes closing my name attribute.